# What's the difference between 一応 and とりあえず?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between `一応{いちおう}` and `とりあえず`?

While I think they can both mean "tentatively" or "for the time being", there seems to be a difference in their usage. How do the two translate differently into English?

After reading [this Space ALC Japanese Q&A page](http://home.alc.co.jp/db/owa/jpn_npa?stage=2&sn=1), I'm interpreting it as that `一応` has a negative nuance of something being "unsatisfactory" but temporally doing it anyway, and that `とりあえず` has a positive (or possibly neutral?) nuance of "doing what you can do for the time being". Can the previous explanations work for all, or a majority of cases?

It also states that in the following sentences there isn't a lot of difference between the two:

> - お話は**一応**伺っておきましょう。
> - **とりあえず**お話は伺っておきましょう。

But I didn't understand why the two have a different position in the sentence. Would `一応お話は伺っておきましょう` and `お話はとりあえず伺っておきましょう` also be possible?

Comment: The position does not matter. Both orders that you ask are possible.

Comment: `一往【いちおう】` looks way cooler.

Comment: I always translated 一応 as "kind of".

Answer (score 19):

- `一応` means "as a backup", "in case something happens". It implies some redundancy.
- `とりあえず` means "can't think of the best way to do at the moment/can't decide for the moment, so for the time being".